# How to pass different parameters to different http request classes that implement the same interface

Tags: c#, oop, interface, architecture

I am developing a C# program that has to do various HTTP request to get different kinds of information (price of a specific item in a region, history of prices for an item, route between two region, etc).

I have started by implementing an IRequest interface that contains two properties that all requests must have:

```
public interface IRequest
{
    ReturnDataType DataReturnType { get; }

    HttpWebRequest HttpRequest { get; }
}

public enum ReturnDataType
{
    Xml,
    Json
};
```

I would like to add in that interface a list (or any other container) that would contain the parameters for the request (to be added in the URL), so that I could access them via referencing the IRequest interface. Unfortunately, since each http request don't necessarily have the same request, and not necessarily in the same order if they do, I do not know how to achieve this. The only solution I came up with is to have a `List<String>` in the interface, and to rely on the programmer to read that parameter x shall always be first in the list for the http request a, parameter y second, etc, parameter z always first for the http request b, etc.

As I am probably going to be the only one touching this code, it probably won't cause problems in the long run, but I would like nonetheless use a better solution if one exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do the following:

```
public class GetItemPriceRequest: IRequest
{
        public string ItemNumber {set;get;}
        public string UserName {set;get;}
}

public GetItemHistoryRequest: IRequest
{
        // my properties
}
```

and so forth for each request. And have a response class for each request. That way is more cleaner and organizing. Moreover, you know what parameters to expect based on the request object type. Meaning, if the request objects passed is of type `GetItemPriceRequest`; then i should see `ItemNumber` field.

I hope that will help you solving your issue. please let me know if you have problems.

Comment: I have a factory that creates the appropriate request and returns an `IRequest`. If I do the following: `GetItemPriceRequest request = (GetItemPriceRequest)RequestFactory(GetItemPriceRequestString)`, will I have access to `ItemNumber` and `UserName` if those properties are populated already?

Comment: GetItemPriceRequestString is the name of the class? or what it is? 
you should get access to item number and username, as long you doing the cast

Comment: Sorry, the real signature for my factory is `CreateApiRequest(ApiRequestType requestType)` where `ApiRequestType` is an enum to indicate which request we want instantiated. Just to confirm, if in the constructor of the `GetItemPriceRequest` class I populate `ItemNumber` and `UserName` with values, I will have access to those values (as populated in the constructor) even though it is returned by `CreateApiRequest(ApiRequestType requestType)` as an IRequest?

Comment: My guess is `CreateApiRequest` will return an object that inherit from `IRequest`. as long as this returned object is casted to your type(`GetItemPriceRequest`), then you will have access to all its properties(`ItemNumber`) after casting.

Answer (score 1):

As addition you could find helpful the [Command design pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/command-design-pattern) - it encapsulates a command request as an object. Further more letting you parameterize clients with different requests, queue or log requests, and support undoable operations.

And how

> to do various HTTP request to get different kinds of information

can help you [ParameterObject](http://refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html) - it deals with a chain of calls (more details [here](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ParameterObject)).